# Error: Package p1 does not exist while compiling java file from package p2

Tags: java, package

```
package p1;
public class Protection {

int n = 1;
private int n_pri = 2;
protected int n_pro = 3;
public int n_pub = 4;

public Protection() {
    System.out.println("base constructor");
    System.out.println("n = " + n);
    System.out.println("n_pri = " + n_pri);
    System.out.println("n_pro = " + n_pro);
    System.out.println("n_pub = " + n_pub);
}
}
```

Package p2 contains three files demo.java, OtherPackage.java and Protection2.java:

```
//Demo package p2.
package p2;

//Instantiate various classes in p2.
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Protection2 ob1 = new Protection2();
    OtherPackage ob2 = new OtherPackage();
}
}

package p2;
```

OtherPackage.java

```
class OtherPackage {
OtherPackage() {
    p1.Protection p = new p1.Protection();
    System.out.println("Other package constructor");

    //class or package only
    //System.out.println("n = " + p.n);

    //class only
    //System.out.println("n_pri = " + p.n_pri);

    //class, subclass or package only
    //System.out.println("n_pro = " + p.n_pro)

    System.out.println("n_pub = " + p.n_pub);
}
}
```

and Protection2.java

```
package p2;

class Protection2 extends p1.Protection {
Protection2() {
    System.out.println("Derived other package constructor");

    //class or package only
    //System.out.println("n = " + n);

    //class only
    //System.out.println("n_pri = " + n_pri);

    System.out.println("n_pro = " + n_pro);
    System.out.println("n_pub = " + n_pub);
}
}
```

I tried compiling Demo.java from package p2:

```
:~/Desktop/Examples/p2$ javac *.java
```

I generates the following errors

```
Protection2.java:3: error: package p1 does not exist
class Protection2 extends p1.Protection {
                        ^
OtherPackage.java:5: error: package p1 does not exist
    p1.Protection p = new p1.Protection();
      ^
OtherPackage.java:5: error: package p1 does not exist
    p1.Protection p = new p1.Protection();
                            ^
Protection2.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("n_pro = " + n_pro);
                                    ^
    symbol:   variable n_pro
    location: class Protection2
Protection2.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("n_pub = " + n_pub);
                                    ^
    symbol:   variable n_pub
    location: class Protection2
5 errors
```

I tried importing package p1 but it adds another error along with the above 5 errors:

```
Demo.java:4: error: package p1 does not exist
import p1.Protection;
```

Comment: try `cd ~/Desktop/Examples` and compile `p2/*.java`

Comment: It can't find `p1` because you haven't told it where to look, so it only looks in current directory by default, and `p1` doesn't exist in the current directory. Do what @ajb said, i.e. run compiler from parent directory, so both `p1` and `p2` exists in the current directory. Alternatively, if you insist on running compiler from `p2`, do it like this: `javac -cp .. *.java`

Answer (score 0):

I made this directory structure:

```
                 package
                    |
       ----------------------------
       |                          |
    source                       bin
       |                          |
( All .java files )       ( Package folders after compilation )
```

**Java Files:**

*Protection.java*

```
package p1;

public class Protection {

    public int m_Pub;

    int m_N;
    private int m_Pri;
    protected int m_Pro;

    public Protection () {
        m_Pub = 4;
        m_N = 1;
        m_Pri = 2;
        m_Pro = 3;

        System.out.println ( "Base Constructor" );
        System.out.println ( "m_Pub = " + m_Pub );
        System.out.println ( "m_N = " + m_N );
        System.out.println ( "m_Pri = " + m_Pri );
        System.out.println ( "m_Pro = " + m_Pro );
    }
}
```

*Demo.java*

```
package p2;

public class Demo {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        Protection2 protection2 = new Protection2 ();
        OtherPackage otherPackage = new OtherPackage ();
    }
}
```

*OtherPackage.java*

```
package p2;

import p1.Protection;

public class OtherPackage {

    public OtherPackage () {
        Protection protection = new Protection ();
        System.out.println ( "OtherPackage Constructor" );
    }
}
```

*Protection2.java*

```
package p2;

import p1.Protection;

public class Protection2 extends Protection {

    public Protection2 () {
        System.out.println ( "Derived Protection2 Constructor" );
        System.out.println ( "m_Pro = " + m_Pro );
        System.out.println ( "m_Pub = " + m_Pub );
    }
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package
$ javac -d bin source/*.java
```

**Execution:**

```
nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package
$ cd bin

nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package/bin
$ java p2.Demo
Base Constructor
m_Pub = 4
m_N = 1
m_Pri = 2
m_Pro = 3
Derived Protection2 Constructor
m_Pro = 3
m_Pub = 4
Base Constructor
m_Pub = 4
m_N = 1
m_Pri = 2
m_Pro = 3
OtherPackage Constructor

nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package/bin
```

The point is, while compiling you failed to specify, where to look for `package p1`, since you are inside folder `p2`. You need to put all `.java` files, during compilation process.

If you are trying to keep each `.java` file in it's respective `package` folder, then it goes like this:

**Directory Structure:**

```
                     package
                        |
           ----------------------------
           |                          |
        source                       bin
           |                          |
     ------------     ( Package folders after compilation )
     |          |
     p1         p2
     |          | 
     |        Demo.java OtherPackage.java Protection2.java
Protection.java
```

**Compilation:**

```
nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package
$ javac -d bin source/p1/*.java source/p2/*.java
```

**Execution:**

```
nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package
$ cd bin

nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package/bin
$ java p2.Demo
Base Constructor
m_Pub = 4
m_N = 1
m_Pri = 2
m_Pro = 3
Derived Protection2 Constructor
m_Pro = 3
m_Pub = 4
Base Constructor
m_Pub = 4
m_N = 1
m_Pri = 2
m_Pro = 3
OtherPackage Constructor

nipal_000@Lenovo-PC /cygdrive/c/mine/java/package/bin
```